# XUnit Gherkin Quick, is there a way to change the way the Test Explorer in visual studio renders the scenarios?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, gherkin

Take this file for example:

```
Feature: Website visitor joins the test service

Scenario: The website visitor becomes a member
Given ....
When ....
Then ...

Scenario: The website visitor is too young to become a member
Given ....
When ....
Then ...
```

When looking at the visual studio test explorer the tree view is too long and it is hard to tell which scenarios has passed without extending the test explorer really wide:

```
MyProject.Specs
-JoinTestServiceSteps
--Website visitor joins the test service :: The website visitor becomes a member :: #1 (2)
---Website visitor joins the test service :: The website visitor becomes a member :: #1
---Website visitor joins the test service :: The website visitor is too young to become a member :: #2
```

Can this be changed to something like:

```
MyProject.Specs
-Feature Website visitor joins the test service (2)
--The website visitor becomes a member :: #1
--The website visitor is too young to become a member :: #2
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question, but thanks for bringing Gherkin.Quick to my attention it's new and shiny!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the display name comes from the ScenarioXunitHook part of the project, of which this class grabs the feature name and the scenario name and concatenates them.

https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/blob/2b753cec8844ee67c9ba10bdf648b1db6f422fc0/source/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/ScenarioXunitHook/ScenarioXUnitTestCase.cs#L37

You may wish to put in a feature request to ask if the display name can be overridden.

However I think the display in the TestExplorer (i.e. it's nesting) is more a feature of the test explorer itself.

You may wish to run the tests via Resharper instead, I haven't used it for a while but if I remember correctly when using it with Specflow it tended to be more user friendly for BDD style test names - but that was some time ago in old VS.

**EDIT:**

Test Explorer can naturally group by "traits"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2017#group-by-traits

You may wish to explore the idea of adding traits to Gherkin Quick to take advantage of it.

It appears that Gerkin Quick will take tags https://github.com/ttutisani/Xunit.Gherkin.Quick/blob/5927588a4f35b81ecea926975eb2815ebf96cbc3/docs/tags.md

And set them as traits in your test, so that could be a great option to explore.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will take a look!